# Is there a pre-existing flight controller framework similar to DJI Go?

Tags: android, dji-sdk

Hello DJI SDK Community,

I'm looking to essentially write a simple plugin for DJI Go (Android) that takes live flight data from the drone and sends it to the internet. From what I can tell, DJI Go doesn't allow plugins, so I'd have to write a flight controller app using the SDK from the ground up and then build my plugin on that.

That sounds like a monumental task, and way out of my league. Does anyone have any ideas for something I could use as a framework that acts as DJI Go (even super basic flight functionality would be great) that I could write my plugin on top of?

My drone:
Phantom 3 Pro

Thanks!

Comment: I know this is late, but for anyone else who sees this: DJI just announced a public beta for a UI library for exactly this reason. In theory it should allow for easy and quick integration into any app. I'm still waiting to get approved. Contact the developers to enroll.

Answer (score 1):

You could start with the [Android Mobile SDK sample app](https://github.com/dji-sdk/Mobile-SDK-Android) which has many of the basic functionality for flight control already coded in.